Redis Stream design question regarding scalability
Can I have 1 redis stream and one consumer group in that stream per user? For Example: each user is going to be generating some content and they will serve that content to a set of users in that consumer group.
Is this scalable? if we have 10,000 users. Can we have 1 stream and 10,000 consumer groups?

You can certainly have a single stream with 10,000 consumers groups. This will work. But, some caveats.
A stream is a key and a key exists on but a single shard. And Redis is single-threaded. So, all access to that stream will be through a single thread on a single shard. In other words, everyone is going to look at the same place, one by one. This could create scalability issues depending on how frequently the stream is populated and/or accessed. In essence, that stream becomes a hot key.
Creating read-only replicas might mitigate this—I'm not exactly sure how consumer groups work with read-only replicas—but a standard cluster that spreads the keys across shards will certainly not help as each key exists in one and only one shard.
All that said, Redis is pretty speedy so this could very well work. It just depends on some of the aforementioned variables. And, of course, your hardware, virtual or otherwise.

wouldn't it be better to have 1 stream per user? (millions of streams on scale)

Yes. That would scale much better.
